# scikit-learn kernel ridge confusion

Tags: python, regression

I wrote the following very simple short code:

```
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge

def kernelize(A, b):
    clf = KernelRidge(alpha=1, kernel='polynomial', degree=2)
    clf.fit(A, b)
```

Where A is a matrix with 12665 rows and 784 columns, and b is a vector with 12665 rows.

As far as I understand, the polynomial kernel should transform our A matrix into a 12665 by 784 * 784 / 2. Why? because instead of having columns c1, c2, ..., c784, we will have columns c1*c1, c1*c2, ... all combinations.

Thus, I expected the solution in kernel space to be 784 * 784 / 2 dimensional vector. But clf.dual_coef_ prints a 12665 dimensional vector, I'm unsure why.

Comment: Because [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge.html) says that it will. You should read more about how KRR works.

Comment: your understanding of the KRR (from `As far as I understand` to `784 * 784 / 2 dimensional vector`) is not correct. Read more about KRR please, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52588587/3059809 or other online resources. the result of sklearn is correct.